# I want to create crud with one to many relationship but getting confusion laravel8

Tags: laravel-8

I want to create something like bellow but not getting how to add multiple companies with single user

```
1.  Add a Company [Name, City]
2.  Add a User [Name, Email, Phone]
3.  Allocate a User to one or more Companies
4.  List Users [Name, Email, Phone, Allocated Companies (comma separated string)]
```

I have created company model nd controller succesfully but not getting how to add user with multiple companies.

Companies table as follows:

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

If anyone have idea plz let me know

Answer (score 0):

If a user has many companies you can do the following:

```
// If you use id
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('company_name');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->id('user_id'); 
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

// If you use uuid
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('company_name');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->uuid('user_uuid'); 
        $table->foreign('user_uuid')->references('uuid')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```